# Conditional cast from 'UIButton' to 'UIButton' always succeeds

Tags: ios, swift

i'm a  newer    on  IOS , when   i  download  other   workspaces   into   my  xcodes,    it  give  some  warnings   on the   project,anyone   helps ?  thanks!!!  so   don't   decrease   my  score, anyone  has  been    a  time  newer? 
this  is  the code

let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as? UIButton

Comment: You dont need as? simply let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) will infer it to proper type.

Comment: you  are   right   ,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the cast. Swift can easily deduce type in this case. This is enough:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .System)
```